# Can't get inline-block divs to stay stuck to the top of parent div

Tags: html, css

I can't get two inline-block divs to both stay stuck to the top of the parent div. One inline-block div sits toward the bottom of the parent div while the other is toward the top.

How can I get both divs to stay at the top?

HTML

```
<div id="middle_page_holder_outside">
        <div id="middle_page_holder">
            <div id="vote_below_slider_holder">
                ...
            </div>
            <div id="polldaddy_holder">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#middle_page_holder_outside {
            width:100%;
            float:left;
            }
            
            #middle_page_holder {
                max-width:610px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:auto;
                }
            
            #vote_below_slider_holder {
                width:300px;
                margin:0 0 30px 0;
                display:inline-block;
                }
            
            #polldaddy_holder {
                width:300px;
                margin:0 0 30px 0;
                display:inline-block;
                }
```

Here's the link:
http://hollywoodrooster.com/alexa-ray-joel-plastic-surgery-nose-job (below the main content - it's the two voting blocks).

Here's a screen shot of the issue

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your css to:

```
 #vote_below_slider_holder {
                width:300px;
                margin:0 0 30px 0;
                display:inline-block;
                vertical-align:top;
                }
```